# my bootstrap modal is not hidden by default

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

My bootstrap model is not hidden by default. I want it to show up only when I click a link.

I am a novice in web development.

**tst.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    >   
    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="modal-fade" id="recordContent">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="recordContentLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         content
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonCustom">Understood</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="" data-toggel='modal' data-target="#recordContent"> Open modal</a>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One strategy I use for problems like this is to inspect a working example with my browser's developer tools, as well as the broken example. Differences in styles often become immediately clear, then you can look to see what the problem is. In your case, two typos meant that two classes and one data attribute were missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of issues you class must be `modal fade` not `modal-fade` and your target attribute modal `data-toggle` not `data-toggel`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    >   
    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="modal fade" id="recordContent" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="recordContentLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         content
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonCustom">Understood</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#recordContent"> Open modal</a>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working now, you might be missing some right piece of code. Please check below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testing</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="recordContent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            content
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#recordContent"> Open modal</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A big gob of code isn't of much value as an answer without some explanation of changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the class for the modal is incorrect.
It needs to be `modal fade`.

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0d9fwz4s

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra dash between your two css classes where you declare your modal:

```
<div class="modal-fade" id="recordContent">
  ...
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="recordContent">
  ...
</div>
```

Without the dash between `modal` and `fade`.
As specified in the doc with this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo

Comment: _Hyphen_, technically. :)